# Repartitioned data bottlenecks in few tasks in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple spark job which does the following

```
val dfIn  = spark.read.parquet(PATH_IN)
val dfOut = dfIn.repartition(col1, col2, col3)
dfOut.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy(col1, col2, col3).parquet(PATH_OUT)
```

I noticed in this job big performance deterioration. Inspecting the Spark UI showed that the write bottlenecked in a few tasks which showed huge memory spill and much bigger output size compared to the fast partitions.

So I suspected that this issue is caused by the data skew and changed the way the data is repartitioned to

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rand
val dfOut = dfIn.withColumn("rand", rand()).repartitionByRange(col1, col2, col3, $"rand")
```

however this did not help to resolve the performance issues.
In the Spark UI you can see now that the data is very evenly distributed across ALL partitions (based on the output size). But still a few tasks are very long running.

I have no ideas what else could cause this and would be thankful for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a final answer for your issue, this tip might help: you can easily inspect your actual data for possible skewness with

```
for i, part in enumerate(dfIn.rdd.glom().collect()):
    print({i: len(part)})
```

and then salting as needed. Of course all data might not fit, limit as appropriate to get a proper sample :)

PS: example in Python but you get the idea

Comment: i know that i have skewed data
the question is why does evenly distributing the data by using repartitionByRange not cure the symptoms

Comment: Did you made some further analysis or just throwed range partitioning at it ? While range partitioning can work most of the time, it cannot be assesed for certain. In some cases range partitioning does not make data balanced. Also it will hard to deduce anything without seeing the physical executed plan log.

Comment: no i did not do some further analysis except reasoning about the metrics presented by the Spark-UI.
this is also were i'm clueless right now - i don't know what i should really investigate any further.

about your concern that range partitioning not making the data balanced
what i'm seeing in the spark-ui is that the output sizes of all partitions are very balanced